# Session Abandon when clicking logout link

Tags: asp.net, session, logout

**Below is my code:**

```
UserName = "Hello :" + Session["Username"].ToString()+ " |   Logout  ";
```

What i want is, when someone clicks the **LogOut**, the session should get abandon.

**How can i achieve the needed result.**

Comment: Well, i tried, but i don't know how to link a text.

Comment: There are may ways instead of that. Watch some tutorials that may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session.Abandon(); will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to remove value and Abandon it.

> Session.RemoveAll();

```
Session.Clear();
Session.Abandon();
```